# Am I misinterpreting this matrix determinant property?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I was reading matrix determinant properties from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Properties_of_the_determinant).

The property reads
$\det(cA) = c^n \det(A)$ for $n \times n$ matrix.

However I am not able to realize it. What I find is $\det(cA) = c\det(A)$

For example, multiplying matrix by 2 and then taking the determinant of the resultant matrix:

$
2\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 5 & 6 \\
6 & 5 & 4 \\
4 & 6 & 5 \\
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
8 & 10 & 12 \\
6 & 5 & 4 \\
4 & 6 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
$
and
$
\begin{vmatrix}
8 & 10 & 12 \\
6 & 5 & 4 \\
4 & 6 & 5
\end{vmatrix}=60
$

Now first taking the determinant and then multiplying by 2 yields the same result:

$$
2\begin{vmatrix}
4 & 5 & 6 \\
6 & 5 & 4 \\
4 & 6 & 5 \\
\end{vmatrix}
= 2 \cdot 30 = 60
$$

Where I am mistaking?

Comment: How exactly do you define multiplication of a matrix by$~2$? It looks more like you only multiplied part of the matrix by$~2$.

Comment: Imagine the scalar multiplication of a siingle row as the scaling of a dimension of the box the determinant respresents the volume of in n-space? If the matrix is order two, then the determinant of this matrix is equivalent to the area of the parallelogram the vectors of this matrix comprise on the plane. Scaling a sinle dimension will scale the area

Comment: Don't mind the question mark. Impossible to edit on the phone :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Multiplying a matrix by a scalar $c$ amounts to multiplying *each* entry by $c$, not just the first row.

Comment: Ohh damn stupid I am, I should delete this question, but I read below property somewhere, which implies so, is it wrong then? 
(Unfortunately I noted down this in my book, have not noted its source.
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
a & kb & c \\
x & ky & z \\
p & kq & r \\
\end{vmatrix}
=
k\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & c \\
x & y & z \\
p & q & r \\
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
ka & kb & kc \\
x & y & z \\
p & q & r \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

Comment: @Mahesha999 The vertical bars represent the determinant. It is not a matrix and is probably the cause of your confusion.

Comment: @JessicaK thanks to point to that...so its just that multiplying matrix by scalar multiplies all elements, but multiplying determinant by scalar multiplies elements of only one row / column

Comment: @Mahesha999: It's just saying that if you multiply *one* row or column of a matrix by a constant $k$, the determinant of the resulting matrix will be $k$ times that of the original.

Answer (score 2):

You have $\det (cB) = \det (cI) \det B $ and you can see from the formula for $\det$ that $\det (cI) = c^n$.

Another way is to notice that $\det$ is a multilinear function of the columns (or rows), that is, we can write
$\det(A) = f(a_1,...,a_n)$ where $a_k$ is the $k$th row of $A$, and $f$ is
linear in each argument separately.

Then $\det(cA) = f(c a_1,...,c a_n) = c f(a_1, c a_2,...,c a_n) = c^2 f(a_1,  a_2,...,c a_n)= \cdots = c^n f(a_1,...,a_n) = c^n \det A$.

**Addendum**:

You multiplied the matrix incorrectly.

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 5 & 6 \\
6 & 5 & 4 \\
4 & 6 & 5
\end{bmatrix}$, $2A = \begin{bmatrix}
8 & 10 & 12 \\
12 & 10 & 8  \\
8 & 12 & 10
\end{bmatrix}$.
$\det A = 30, \det (2A) = 240$.

Comment: Though true, I don't think you really answered the question. I guess OP found things like this at WP already (and says so).

Answer (score 1):

$$2 \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 6 & 5 & 4 \\ 4 & 6 & 5 \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} 8 & 10 & 12 \\ 12 & 10 & 8 \\ 8 & 12 & 10 \end{bmatrix}.$$

You only multiplied the first row by 2.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to see that the answer is $c^n \det A$. One is by using the full expansion formula and noting that each term in the full expansion is a product of $n$ matrix entries and each matrix entry has multiplied by $c$. There is also a geometric explanation: The determinant gives the (signed) volume of the parallelopiped spanned by the columns of your matrix. If you dialate by a positive factor $c$, then the parallelopied is dialated by a factor of $c$ in each dimension, so the volume is dialated by a factor of $c^n$.